# FusionPro/Javascript Programming

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I am a Web Developer looking for assistance with FusionPro or writing Javascript for the FusionPro Plug-In. This seems to be a niche technology, and so I'm writing my appeal here where hopefully it will be seen by a larger group of professionals.

The largest issue we are currently facing is that we are having trouble with CopyFitting text-frames. This copyfitting reduces the size of the text-frames to make text fit, and this reduction results in the random re-sizing of text, the disappearance of lines after they 'fall out' of the text frame, among other issues. We use multiple text frame's on a design, filled with variables, and then through a database we insert default information(depending on the template) & our customers are able to edit these variables as-well.